# Console loggin a MongoDB collection. Undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm creating a Node project cause i want to knwo how to use `mongoose` but i'm facing a problem right now. I'm getting an `undefined` variable while returing a collection from my MongoDB database. This is my code:

app.js

```
...
case 'index-user':
        let indexUserResponse = userController.index();
        console.log(indexUserResponse); // undefined
        break;
...
```

user.js (controller)

```
...
const index = () => {
    User.find({}, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res;
    });
}
...
```

I know that there is a user on the database and i can see it if add a `console.log(user)` just before the `return res;` so... What is happening here? I don't get it.

Comment: Might not be a duplicate as the question implies that the user didn't know it is an async call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `userController.index()` is an calling an async function.
You should use a callback or a promise in order to fetch the data from you db.
Promise example:
Here we are returning a promise from the the executing the query on the `Users` collection.

```js
const index = () => User.find({}).exec();
```

And in `app.js`:

```js
case 'index-user':
        userController.index().then(result => {
          console.log(result); // as you use find there will be a list of user documents
        });
        break;
```

Or, you can use good old `callbacks` as so:

```js
const index = (callback) => {
    User.find({}, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return callback(res);
    });
}
```

And in `app.js`:

```js
case 'index-user':
        let indexUserResponse = userController.index((result) => {
          console.log(result); 
        });
        break;
```

When you execute it the way you do now, the `console.log()` runs before the `index()` method can execute the `find()` callback.

Hope it's clear enough and helps

Comment: This works just fine! Thanks a lot!